# Deleting multiple records with node-oracledb executeMany

Tags: node.js, oracle, node-oracledb

I want to delete multiple rows from oracle db on nodejs project.
I am using oracledb (4.0.1) with node (v10.14.2)

While im doing i got error which is like that; `{"level":50,"time":1573197878989,"msg":"Failed: Error: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library is at version 11.2 but must be at version 12.1 or higher Case: ora.deleteMany","pid":11092,"hostname":"***","v":1}`
According to that error it claims that Oracle Client issue. But my Oracle Client is already **12.2.0.1.0**.

I can use `SELECT` and `UPDATE` queries on my current project successfully without getting any errors. Now i want to use `DELETE` query while im doing i got that error.

I will explain how i code down below.

Those are ID's what i want to delete from table. `[ { ID: 11865 }, { ID: 23249 } ]`
I generate that json list by using `SELECT` query. It returned to me that IDs to delete as a json list.

```
const getTodayDailyDiff = async config => {
  let test = [];
  const today = new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];
  let connection;
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(config);
    test = await connection.execute(
      `
    (SELECT ID FROM TNT.DAILY_DIFF
      WHERE TO_CHAR(DIFF_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = :today)
      `,
      [today]
    );
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err, 'ora.diffReport');
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      connection.close();
    }
  }
  return test;
};
```

Then i send that json list(`getTodayDailyDiff.rows`) to my `DELETE` query.

```
const deleteMany = async (config, getTodayDailyDiff.rows) => {
  let test = [];
  let connection;
  const sql = `DELETE FROM DAILY_DIFF WHERE ID = :ID`;
  const options = {
    dmlRowCounts: true,
    autoCommit: true
  };
  try {
    connection = await oracledb.getConnection(config);
    test = await connection.executeMany(sql, getTodayDailyDiff.rows, options);
  } catch (err) {
    log.error(err, 'ora.deleteMany');
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      connection.close();
    }
  }
  return test;
};
```

Comment: Run https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/master/examples/version.js to check what client version Node.js is using.  Regardless of the version, combine the SQL as shown by @Diver's answer.

Comment: I checked client version on nodejs. It looks like im using Client 11.2.0.1.0. Actually i have client version 12.2.0.1.0. I guess even i have higher version of client, It still works on old client.  ````Run at: Mon Nov 11 2019 10:14:31 GMT+0300 (GMT+03:00)
Node.js version: v10.14.2 (win32 x64)
Node-oracledb version: 4.0.1
Oracle Client library version: 11.2.0.1.0
Oracle Database version: 12.2.0.1.0````

Comment: You actually have 11.2.  It may be in your PATH before the later version, or it may be in some default system directory.  Search your file system for all oci.dll files.

Comment: ````Node.js version: v10.14.2 (win32 x64)
Node-oracledb version: 3.0.1
Oracle Client library version: 19.3.0.0.0
Oracle Database version: 12.2.0.1.0```` i update my client now im not getting that error while on  ````DELETE```` query running. Thank you

Comment: It's odd that you got a newer Instant Client but older node-oracledb !

Comment: after i wrote that comment, i updated oracledb version also but i couldnt edit my comment. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't address the client issue but maybe a better solution would be to combine those two calls and save yourself a trip to the database.

```
DELETE FROM DAILY_DIFF WHERE ID in (SELECT ID FROM TNT.DAILY_DIFF
      WHERE TO_CHAR(DIFF_DATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '${today}')
```

Comment: But use a bind variable instead of ${today}.  Otherwise you have a security issue, and a potential performance/scalability issue if the statement is executed multiple times.

Comment: Actually i code first like @Diver wrote, then i got some errors. I changed it. First i ll try change client version on nodejs. Then i ll follow what you said to me

Comment: @ChristopherJones thank you for your advice, i used a bind variable.